# Python writing too much

Tags: python, file

I've looked around the web and can't find an answer, sorry if I missed it.

I'm trying to simply replace some lines in a file, do something with this modified file, then rewrite it to its original state. So I keep a copy of the base file, modify the one I need to do something with, then rewrite the base file into the modified one.

Here's my code :

```
lines = open('fileToModify').readlines()
for i, line in enumerate(lines[:]):
    if "STRING" in line:
        lines[i] = line.replace("STRING", sys.argv[1])
    if "STRING2" in line:
        lines[i] = line.replace("STRING2", sys.argv[2])
pfile = open("fileToModify", "r+")
pfile.seek(0)
pfile.writelines(lines)
pfile.seek(0)
baseLines = open("baseFile").readlines()
pfile.writelines(baseLines)
pfile.close()
```

The problem is that when I rewrite the base file to the modified one, the last 2 chars of the base file are copied into a new line of the modified file. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, it seems really strange to me ...

Also if there is a better way to achieve this purpose, I'm up to any suggestions.

Thank's in advance !

Comment: Why not just write the modified lines to a second tempfile, and just use that? Overwriting and then restoring the original file seems unnecessary, and error-prone.

Comment: @tzaman +1. I feel stupid.

Comment: So I just did that, still it's copying too much data into the temp file (this time  the 3 last chars of the base file). So I seriously think I'm doing something wrong, but what ?

Comment: In addition, if you open a file with mode 'r+' and seek to the beginning, if you then write less bytes than the current file size will leave you some bytes at the end of the file. Use mode w or w+ instead

Comment: @Antwane You were right, just changing the file opening mode did the trick. Sorry about the dumb question, I don't know much about python file read/write. Thank's !

Answer (score 1):

```
from shutil import copy

s1, r1 = "STRING", sys.argv[1]
s2, r2 = "STRING2", sys.argv[2]

with open("orig_file") as in_f, open("new_file", "w") as out_f:
    for line in in_f:
        out_f.write(line.replace(s1, r1).replace(s2, r2))

copy("new_file", "orig_file")
```